# What signal should I capture to grab the text of Gtk::Entry before it is changed?

Tags: c++, gtk, signals, gtkmm

I am writing an application using gtkmm 3 (running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) and working right now with the Gtk::Entry control.

I cannot find the correct signal to capture so that I can grab the  Gtk::Entry buffer text before it is changed, and persist it to maintain a record of changes. I know that in some other tool-kits, there is a hook provided that facilitates such. (I believe using a "shadow buffer".)

What signal do I have to grab to do this? What is the slot's signature for this signal? Is this functionality supported at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give a try to GObject's "notify" signal. It is used in conjunction with the property to spy. Connecting to "notify::text" will call your callback for each modification of the "text" property, but the first change may be the setter that will set the initial value, that you could then store. Worth a try.

Otherwise, you could try to store it on the first triggering of the "insert-text" or "delete-text" signals. Please give use some feedback if that seems to work.

I also agree with DanielKO: on an usability point of view, modifying user input is just annoying and bad practice. Better to tell her which field is wrong, put the focus there, and/or have a button to reset to defaults, but not enforce any change on user input.

Comment: The implementation has nothing to do with that, and I've seen enough problems with this kind of approach to warn you. If you don't care, that's your problem, but don't ask us to teach you bad practice.

Comment: Don't know what you're talking about, or why you are referring to DanielKO's irrelevant remarks.

Comment: Have you ever used one of those websites (I saw this on installers too) that assume that, when some specific text entries (say, zip code or telephone number) are full, you want to tab to the next entry in the form? Then you realize you made a mistake, and now whenever you want to shift-tab back to correct it, the script will sends the focus again to the next empty entry? That's the kind of usability breakage you are getting into. My remark is relevant because the GTK+ developers care a lot about usability, and won't provide features that cause usability problems.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are changing the behaviour, it's better to inherit from `Gtk::Entry`:

```
class ValidatedEntry : public Gtk::Entry {

    Glib::ustring last_valid;

    virtual void on_changed()
    {
        Glib::ustring text = get_text();
        if (... validation here ...)
            set_text(last_valid); // WARNING: will call this on_changed() again
        else
            last_valid = text;
        Gtk::Entry::on_changed(); // propagate down
    }
};
```

## BUT

This goes against usability, that's why it's not a built-in behaviour. Users won't like the text reverting back just because they miss-typed something; they might hit backspace before they realize the entry threw the wrong character away.

You should at least wait until the user presses the Enter key (i.e. `signal_activate` or override `on_activate()`), or do something less drastic, like showing a warning icon.

Comment: There is no signal for catching a change in the text before it happens. The best you can do is intercept the `Gtk::Widget`'s [`key_press_event`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a5d011cc0cfa3993bc342ccff612c13ff) and cancel the entire chain before it gets to the `Gtk::Entry` (i.e. return `true` from it); the code to do this properly is probably as large as the one I suggested.

Comment: This does not answer the question but appears to be a viable approach to the problem. However the usability aspect is irrelevant to the question and makes way too many assumptions and generalizations - it all depends on the implementation details, which are not part of the question at all, and belong on SE.UserExperience, not here.

Comment: This appears to be the best solution for the GTK Entry control. Some other toolkits that implement a hook to grab the old text before the new text is entered use a temporary 'shadow buffer' that hold and displays your pending edits until you hit 'enter' which then commits to the underlying control buffer, etc.

Comment: Don't know why you added "But.." - see question: I mentioned nothing about user interaction - you should remove this irrelevant part of your answer.

Comment: That's a justification for GTK+ lacking that kind of functionality. Do extra spaces render the input invalid? Would that stop me from copy/pasting from a web browser which tends to add tabs and newlines around the selected text? What if I copy an almost correct string, to edit it after pasting? What about IMEs? What if I'm blind, and I'm using a speech recognition software to input the text? Will you bother to test all those cases before claiming your validation doesn't break usability?

Comment: Who is talking about validation? I have changed to question, with the specific intent of making your addition irrelevant, since it was not integral to the answer, but a gratuitous aside.

Comment: @Vector Your attitude here is totally uncalled for. Asking DanielKO to remove a valid part of his answer is unseemly. Even if the remark doesn't apply to your situation specifically, it's appropriate in relation to the question. StackOverflow isn't just for you, the original asker, it's also for the people who have the same question after you and find this. The remark can be helpful to them. The remark could've also been helpful to you - he had no way of knowing, so it was better to give more information rather than less. This answer answers your question, whining about the remark is unseemly.

Comment: @AleksiTorhamo : If you think something is out of line, then flag it, that's all. I stated my opinion and edited the question, which is my right to do, in order to emphasize what my focus was. Usability was not an issue for me at all this case, and in fact there is another SE site devoted entirely to that subject - it's called SE.ux! As I mentioned in one of the comments, I was interested only in signal capture, and a good answer sticks to the question. Be that is it may, this is a site for **posts,** not **Posters...**.